Installing single-pole motion sensor switch in a 3-way switch setup
I have two switches controlling a hallway light. I want to install single-pole Lutron Maestro Motion Sensor (MS-OPS2-WH). I will not need the other switch which could be dead or non-functional after this install. I don’t have enough knowledge to figure out the wiring and thus I would appreciate your expertise.
The install location is in the hallway just under the light. I believe power comes to this switch. When I test with non-contact device, either black line attached to the color screw and red line have power OR two black lines have power when the light is off, depending on switch is used to turn it off.
The other (un-wanted) switch is a part of three gang switch. When I test with non-contact device, either red line is live OR the top black line is live when the light is off, depending on the switch is used to turn it off.
This is like a puzzle and I am wondering how I do go about wiring those two switches for a safe and long-term reliable manner. I also realize that the ground not connected to the switch is not safe and I shall rectify that issue as well.



[4



It might be possible if that switch has the power.  Three ways are confusing and I think I read on here there might be up to eight ways to connect them.  If lucky you will have switch to light to switch.

The most straightforward way (not necessarily the fastest or easiest) to figure out the wiring on a set of 3-way switches is:

Turn off the breaker
Tag all the wires going to each three-way switch so you reattach them in the same places later
Remove all wires going to each three-way switch and spread them apart so they can be tested safely
Turn on the breaker
Use a non-contact voltage tester (NCVT) such as this Klein from Amazon and/or a multimeter such as this Klein from Amazon to check switch wire for power:



You should find exactly one hot wire - that is "incoming hot" - label it
Turn off the breaker
The remaining two wires on that three-way switch are "travelers" - label them
It should be easy to figure out the travelers on the other three-way switch - they will match colors with the travelers on the first switch and, if the switches are the same type, screw locations - label them
The remaining wire on the other three-way switch is "switched hot" - label it

Note that you will also need neutral for most (not necessarily all) motion sensor switches. Fortunately, both of your boxes have wire nuts with multiple white wires in them. Those should be neutral. Add a pigtail (a ~ 6" long white wire, 14 AWG or 12 AWG if it is a 15A circuit, 12 AWG if it is a 20A circuit) to the wire nut. You may need larger wire nuts, or possibly new wire nuts even if the size is OK for an extra wire as they sometimes don't work well for reuse.
Since both boxes appear to have neutral, you can use either one. Let's call the box with "incoming hot" box 1 and the box with "switched hot" box 2.
To install the switch in box 1:

Box 1: "incoming hot" goes to "line" or "hot" on the new switch
Box 1: Pick one "traveler" and attach it to "load" or "switched hot" on the new switch
Box 1: Cap the other "traveler" with a wire nut - you will not use it
Box 2: Use a wire nut to connect the "traveler that is now load/switched hot" to the old "switched hot" wire
Box 2: Cap the other "traveler" with a wire nut - you will not use it

If you install the switch in box 2:

Box 1: Use a wire nut to connect "incoming hot" to a "traveler"
Box 1: Cap the other "traveler" with a wire nut - you will not use it
Box 2: Attach the "traveler that is now incoming hot" to "line" or "hot" on the new switch
Box 2: Attach "switched hot" to "load" or "switched hot" on the new switch
Box 2: Cap the other "traveler" with a wire nut - you will not use it


Thank you for your detailed suggestions. I will follow these. Appreciated.
